# Exclude Empty association array using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations

I have a menus table with a one-to-many self association so basically structure is like

```
---Menu
    |
    '--submenu
    |
    '--submenu

---secondMenu
    |
    '--submenu
            |
            '--submenu
            |
            '--submenu
---thirdMenu
```

Consider the third menu that does not have any submenu. In that case I want the submenu field to be null or this field should not be attached. I get results like

```
"menu": [
        {
            "name": "Settings",
            "id": 37,
            "slug": "Settings-ecom",
            "url": "/Settings",
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "name": "Settings-child1",
                    "id": 38,
                    "slug": "Settings-ecom-child1",
                    "url": "/Settings-child1",
                    "submenu": [
                        {
                            "name": "Settings-child1-child1",
                            "id": 40,
                            "slug": "Settings-ecom-child1-child1",
                            "url": "/Settings-child1-child1",
                            "submenu": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Dashboard",
            "id": 30,
            "slug": "dashboard-ecommerce",
            "url": "/dashboard",
            "submenu": []
        }
    ]
```

consider the `submenu=[]` part in the result, what I need is that when there is no submenu it should not return `submenu = []` . either it should exclude submenu or it should be something like `submenu = null`
below is my query to get menus

```
const menu = await Menu.findAll({
                    where: {parent_id: null},
                    attributes: Constants.attributes,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Menu,
                            as: 'submenu',
                            attributes: Constants.attributes,
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: Menu,
                                    as: 'submenu',
                                    attributes: Constants.attributes,
                                   
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                });
```

and finally the association is like

```
menu.hasMany(models.menu, {
            as: 'submenu',
            foreignKey: 'parent_id',
            useJunctionTable: false,
         });
```

Thanks for looking over my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive call to delete these submenus would work, if submenu does not have children, it should be deleted else child nodes of that menu should be processed until an empty submenu is found.

```js
 cleanMenusObject = async (menuToUpdate) => {

    for (const { dataValues } of menuToUpdate) {
        if (dataValues.submenu) {
           const { submenu } = dataValues;
           if (!submenu.length) {
              delete submenu;
              return;
           } else {
              await cleanMenusObject(submenu);
           }
        }
    }
};
```